# Delaying javascript $(window).load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, delay, bootstrap-modal, window-load

I realize that there are tons of posts on this website that ask about how to delay JavaScript. I have tried numerous ways, but since I am not knowledgeable on JavaScript, I have no idea how to do it.

I am trying to delay the following JavaScript code for 3 seconds. It launches a Bootstrap modal upon page load.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#leave').modal({
        show : true,
        backdrop : 'static' 
    });
});
```

I have tried the following things, but they seem to either break the code, or do not work.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#leave').modal({
            show : true,
            backdrop : 'static' 
        });
    });
},"3000");
```

(breaks it)

---

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#leave').delay(3000).modal({
        show : true,
        backdrop : 'static' 
    });
});
```

(doesn't delay it)

---

```
$(window).delay(3000).load(function(){
    $('#leave').modal({
        show : true,
        backdrop : 'static' 
    });
});
```

(doesn't delay it)

---

If anyone could help me figure out how to delay the code for 3 seconds, I would much appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a number, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#leave').modal({
            show : true,
            backdrop : 'static' 
        });
    },3000);
});
```

`.delay()` only delays execution of subsequent items in the queue ( animation ).